# Service descriptor error and have no clue where its coming from

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

[image]

I converted old MVC project to .net core 3.1 and started receiving this error and have no clue where its coming from. there is no build error or anything but at runtime this error is coming.

As far as i know all all the services are properly injected ins startup file.

Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are getting a load error here:

[image]

It appears this class was moved to a different namespace in [this commit](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/commit/b18526cdc8d8c868e8d7f9c6c8484064215e1002).

Are you using a pre-compiled .dll that is referencing the old version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll? If so, update your reference to compile against the 3.1 version.